# aggregating non-date time series in r

Tags: r, time

I'm trying to aggregate a non-date time series to one hour intervals in R, but every way that I've found starts with "convert to `POSIXct`", which I don't want to do because it slaps today's date on everything, and date is irrelevant for what I'm doing anyway.  These are timestamps in the HH:MM sense, from 00:00 to 23:59.  What I'd like to do is aggregate each hour in a day, and optionally also be able to break it out further into PdDistrict as well.  (So this dataset would break down to a count of rows for the 8:00 hour on Wednesday, one for the 8:00 hour on Thursday, and one for the single 9:00 event on Thursday.  If I could then say "*x* occurrences on Wednesday at 8:00 in Park", so much the better.)

**EDIT:**  I forgot to mention that I'm also having a similar problem trying to use the timestamps as an axis on a plot; the closest I've gotten is with `scale_x_time()`, but that looks like it's interpreting the time as min:sec, e.g., 00:08:30.

```
"DayOfWeek","Time","PdDistrict"
"Wednesday","08:30","NORTHERN"
"Wednesday","08:00","PARK"
"Thursday","08:30","TARAVAL"
"Thursday","08:00","SOUTHERN"
"Wednesday","08:00","NORTHERN"
"Wednesday","08:00","CENTRAL"
"Wednesday","08:00","BAYVIEW"
"Thursday","08:00","PARK"
"Wednesday","08:30","CENTRAL"
"Thursday","08:00","SOUTHERN"
"Wednesday","08:00","CENTRAL"
"Thursday","08:00","SOUTHERN"
"Wednesday","08:30","SOUTHERN"
"Thursday","9:30","BAYVIEW"
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
  group_by(DayOfWeek, 
         Timegroup = format(ceiling_date(as.POSIXct(Time,
               format = "%H:%M"), "hour"), "%H")) %>% 
 summarise(n = n()) 
# A tibble: 5 x 3
# Groups:   DayOfWeek [2]
#  DayOfWeek Timegroup     n
#  <chr>     <chr>     <int>
#1 Thursday  08            4
#2 Thursday  09            1
#3 Thursday  10            1
#4 Wednesday 08            5
#5 Wednesday 09            3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(DayOfWeek = c("Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Thursday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Wednesday", "Thursday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Wednesday", 
"Thursday"), Time = c("08:30", "08:00", "08:30", "08:00", "08:00", 
"08:00", "08:00", "08:00", "08:30", "08:00", "08:00", "08:00", 
"08:30", "9:30"), PdDistrict = c("NORTHERN", "PARK", "TARAVAL", 
"SOUTHERN", "NORTHERN", "CENTRAL", "BAYVIEW", "PARK", "CENTRAL", 
"SOUTHERN", "CENTRAL", "SOUTHERN", "SOUTHERN", "BAYVIEW")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Comment: When I try that I get:

 `Error in UseMethod("reclass_date", orig) : 
  no applicable method for 'reclass_date' applied to an object of class "c('Period', 'Timespan', 'numeric', 'vector')"`

I cut & pasted your full sample above (and copied my test dataset to "df1").

Comment: @jml Can youy check now

Comment: That's closer, but it looks like it's rounding up :30 and above to the next hour.  For this case I'd like to have 8:00 to 8:59 all counted together.

Comment: @jml  Here, I used the ceiling to be 'hourly'.  Not clear what your expected would be